# ifstream::is_open vs ifstream::fail?

Tags: c++, ifstream

Reading Savitch's *Problem Solving in C++*, `std::ifstream::fail` is shown as an example to check if a file has been correctly opened (`ifstream` or `ofstream`).

I've previously used, as it is what I was first shown, `std::ifstream::is_open` to perform the same check.

Which is 'better' practice?

Or in the case that either one is called directly after attempting to open, does it make no practical difference?

Comment: Because we are not for opinion based/best practice/coding-style.  Sorry. Use simply what makes your code more clear to understand. If you test is_open prior writing will it make sense. If you testing it after creation, fail makes more sonse from the context.

Comment: @HelgeBecker This is 10 years old.

Comment: @HelgeBecker This is 10 years old.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### INTRODUCTION

`std::ifstream::fail` includes checking `std::ifstream::is_open`, but `std::ifstream::is_open` only checks if it was possible to create a handle to the file.

---

#### EXPLANATION

`std::ifstream::fail` can return *true*, even if `std::ifstream::is_open` returns *true*; they are not the mutually exclusive.

`.fail` will check the overall *"health"* of the stream, which involves things such as checking the stream has currently entered a *fail state* from trying to read an invalid value, whereas `.is_open` will only check if the stream is currently attached to a file, `.is_open` doesn't care if the stream is in a *fail state*, or not.

---

#### WHAT'S THE BETTER PRACTICE?

This certainly depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Normally it's recommended to rely on the [`explicit operator bool ()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) to see if a stream is ready to be read/written to. This includes checking the overall health of the stream.

Can we make another read/write operation on `some_stream`?

```
if (some_stream) {
  // stream is alive and well
} else {
  // something is wrong
}
```

If you explicitly would like to see if some *fstream* is actually attached to a file, use `is_open`, and if you want to check the overall health; use `.fail` or rely on the fact that a stream is convertiable to `bool`.

Comment: It explains the difference between `is_open()` and `fail()` in detail, but still does not answer the main question of OP: is there any difference when using both _just after file stream object creation_. Specifically, are there and what are the cases when `fail() && is_open()` just after file stream creation.

Answer (score 14):

Use the `bool` conversion operator instead!

```
ifstream i("test.txt");
if (i) {
    //success
}
```

Or better:

```
ifstream i("test.txt");
if (!i) {
    //failure, handle error
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that could be done. What makes it better? If the file is open but empty, does it return true?

Comment: @OllieFord as the [reference says](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), it's essentially a nice shordhand for `!fail()`. It is good, because it's easy to remember and it calls the correct function to check if the stream is ok. (and not `eof()`, `bad()`, etc.)

Comment: why second one is better?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal Because a rest of code will be written for successful case, therefore you will have to put a lot of code in condition, but it will be bad readable. So it is better to just make a few actions in the fail condition and write your rest code without additional block of code