# Same code to write an array to a file writes 1 line less on Linux compared to Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, visual-studio

**EDIT:** Problem solved. @sth asked whether or not I was forgetting to delete the object I might have created with "new". He was right! I was forgetting it. And fixing that indeed fixed the issue. I guess it's something that Visual Studio was doing for me and Linux wasn't.

**EDIT 2:** Code is removed due to this being a school project and potential issues of plagiarism even though I wrote the code myself. Also the issue seems to be unrelated to the specifics of my code and more of a general c++ use case of new and delete.

Exact same code behaves differently on Visual Studio 2013 (installed on Windows) and ssh server of my school in which I use g++ to compile the code. Code compiles without an error and works as intended except for 1 part. It writes 1 line less when writing the contents of an array to a file line by line.

If the array has 10 elements Visual Studio compiled code creates the "sorted.txt" file with 10 lines and all of them hold exactly 1 integer. No empty lines. Ssh compiled code still creates 10 lines however the last line is empty. So there is actually 1 integer missing in my "sorted.txt" file. My assignment will be compiled on this server when being graded so this might be a problem.

Comment: Does the program somehow get terminated without properly cleaning up the `FileManager` object?

Comment: Run valgrind on Linux. You may found the `FileManager` instance leaking.

Comment: @sth I'm not sure if I can check that. The code executes without errors and the ssh terminal simply asks me to write new commands. It doesn't give me any information.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Suggestion: Rather than exposing `numberArray` as a public member, make it private and implement `int & operator[](int index){return numberArray[index]}`.

Comment: Does your program call a function like `exit()`/`abort()` /... to terminate itself? Or do you allocate the `FileManager` with `new`, but never `delete` it?

Comment: @user4581301 I have that code already in the project but it is not being used. I am sorting up to 1 million numbers using different algorithms from a static class so I chose to make the numberArray public in an attempt to gain some time by removing call of two functions each time as the algorithm sorts the array. I am aware that writing the array as private is the preferred way of doing it.

Comment: A function that trivial will be compiled down to the array access by any modern compiler. You lose nothing and gain a better level of encapsulation.

Comment: @user4581301 alright, noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::ofstream` is a buffered stream. If it is not properly closed or flushed, some buffered data might not be written to disk.

In your case the `std::ofstream` would be cleaned up whenever the containing `FileManager` is destroyed. So likely that doesn't happen. It might be that the `FileManager` is dynamically allocated with `new` and never gets destroyed with `delete`, or that the program is abnormally terminated, for example with the C library function `exit()`.

Only the last line is affected by this problem since `std::endl` flushes the stream and forces the previous data to be written to disk.

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains logic to avoid writing a newline at the end of the last line. That's silly, and it feels a bit construed. You need the newline.

Comment: We are given a "data.txt" file which includes randomly placed integers. I am suppose to sort those integers and create a "sorted.txt" file which contains the sorted integers. The original "data.txt" file has no line at the end so I was just trying to mimic that, simply for the presentation. Is there any reason that last line is necessary?

Comment: Why would he *need* the newline?

Comment: `std::endl;` forces a flush of the stream. Alf, should the output stream not flush on close at its destruction? Assuming the program isn't crashing on exit and not destroying. Could be a deeper problem.

Comment: @user4581301: Yes *if* the stream object is destroyed then it's flushed. For the case where it's not destroyed I'm not sure about the C++ level.

Answer (score 1):

When I first saw your code, I thought that it was strange that you are closing the stream based on the bool operator of the stream. You can read about what bool operator does [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/). And, as described [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097580/ifstreamis-open-vs-ifstreamfail), the bool operator can return false even if the stream is still open. Consider closing the stream based on this condition:

```
if (output.is_open ())
```

rather than

```
if (output)
```

Comment: The call `output.close()` is redundant. The destructor of `std::ofstream` will take care of that.

Comment: No need for either, actually. fstream will close on destruction.

Comment: Well, I remember having some issues like this, back in the day, if the stream.close () was not called. Can't tell on what OS it was happening though. That's why I thought that it was the case for OP as well.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Noted. Thanks for the suggestion.