# Checking C++ file stream is opened

Tags: c++

I know this is probably a very common question, but I did not find any good answer for it. When we are using streams to access files in C++, there are two ways to check if we can use stream:

```
std::fstream fs("some_file", std::ios::in);
if (!fs.is_open()) {
// method 1 error checking
}
if (!fs) {
// method 2 error checking
}
```

I know the second method checks fail bits and is different from first method, but I like to know if is it ok to just only use `is_open()` only or not. Because in most examples on internet, I only see `is_open()` is used. Is there any benefit to use `operator!` rather than `is_open()` practically? Does it make any difference between opening for writing or reading?

Comment: I like `is_open` for checks of whether or not a file is open because of the laser-focus of the function on the problem you are testing for and because the failure case you are looking for is spelled out in the code. The goal of `if (!fs)` is far more ambiguous than `if (!fs.is_open())`.

Comment: `if (fs)` or `if (!fs)` is less typing.

Comment: Well. Two comments, two opinions. Such is the way of things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ifstream::is\_open vs ifstream::fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097580/ifstreamis-open-vs-ifstreamfail)

Comment: @DavidJones The question is similar to mine, but even there is no good answer for it as mentioned in the comments. When the stream is created, it is somehow not obvious if there is any difference or not.

Comment: Performance-wise [the difference will be so minute](https://godbolt.org/z/Pq493zeEY) that you'd have to be opening a lot of file and doing absolutely nothing with them to even notice. That leaves personal opinion on which looks better/maximizes programmer productivity in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_open()` simply tells you whether or not the stream has *opened* the file. Nothing more.

`operator bool`, `operator!`, `good()`, `fail()`, etc tell you whether or not the stream is in an *error state*.

Two completely different and unrelated concepts!

The stream can have the file open, and yet still be in an error state due to other operations failing that are not related to opening the file (ie, bad data conversions, etc).  But if the file fails to open, the stream is *also* put into an error state.

Answer (score 0):

`!fs` is equivalent to calling `.fail()` according to [this reference](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_not/).

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I know `!fs` is equivalent to calling `.fail()`. But I like to know what is better to check if file is opened for reading.